# variable array + regular expression not working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im making a small smiley script , what it does is to change ::1:: into an image html for a div.

the code as follow:

```
var smileys = {
  '1': 'http://domain.com/smiley1.gif',
  '2': 'http://domain.com/smiley2.gif',
  '3': 'http://domain.com/smiley3.gif'
};

function checksmileys(){   
x$('.message').each(function() 
  var start = '<img src="';
  var end = '">';
  x$(this).html( x$(this).html().replace(/::(\d+)::/g, start + smileys['$1'] + end) );
});
```

Checksmileys function is triggered by user event.

However it is not able to get the digit(which is the id) out of a sentence.
It kept on producing this `<img src="undefined">`

My HTML example as follows:

```
<div id="chat">
   <ul>
     <li class="message">Hi john</li>
     <li class="message">what are you doing</li>
     <li class="message">::1:: nothing</li>
     <li class="message">hi</li>
     <li class="message">nice to meet you ::1::</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Where is my problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need a function here:

```
html = html.replace(/::(\d+)::/g, function($0, $1) { return start + smileys[$1] + end })
```

here's when the functional form of `html()` comes in handy

```
$(this).html(function(_, oldhtml) { 
    return oldhtml.replace(/::(\d+)::/g, function($0, $1) { 
        return start + smileys[$1] + end; 
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, property names don't have prefixes like they often do in PHP. The name of the property you create in your `smileys` object is `1`, not `$1`, so change `smileys['$1']` to `smileys['1']`.

**Update**: From your comment below, it seems you're trying to use `$1` to refer to the capture group. That only works when `$1` is part of the string you pass in, but the expression `start + smileys['$1'] + end` is evaluated **before** the call to `replace` and then passed into it. `smileys['$1']` will be undefined.

Since you're trying to do a lookup, your best bet is to pass in a function that does the lookup:

```
x$(this).html( x$(this).html().replace(/::(\d+)::/g, function(m, c1) {
    return start + smileys[c1] + end;
}) );
```

`c1` is the text of the first capture group. [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

---

You've called it an array, which I'm guessing is because you're used to the term "associative array" from PHP. Your `smileys` object is just an object, not an array. In JavaScript, when we say "array", we mean something created via `[]` or `new Array`, which has specific handling for a certain class of property names (numeric ones), a special `length` property, and some handy array-like functions. What you've done with `smileys` is perfectly fine and completely normal, we just tend not to use the word "array" for it ("map" is more common in the JS world).

Comment: no , $1 is from the regular expression. it gets 1 out of ::1::

Comment: @sm21guy: No, it isn't. To be used in the regular expression, it has to be part of the string you're passing into `replace`. But it isn't, the expression it's a part of is evaluated before `replace` is called, and then passed into it. `$1` in your code is the name of a property you're looking up on `smiley`. With your code above, `smileys['$1']` will be `undefined`. Nothing whatsoever to do with `replace`.

Comment: @sm21guy: I've updated the answer to show you how to do what you're trying to do.